# No Performance Gain from Increasing CPUs in Docker Container for Parallel API Requests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, docker, .net-6.0

In order to solve a performance problem at work. I have created a very simple set up. I have hosted a .NET 6 API on docker on my computer. ie. Intel® Core™ i3-6100 CPU with 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

The API is very simple. It's the default endpoint that gets created out of the box:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

I am calling this API (running on docker) from my host computer 10000 times in parallel.

**First, I tried it with :**

`docker run -d --name c1m256 --cpus="1" --memory="256m" -p 8081:80 performancetest2`

**And then with:**

`docker run -d --name c2m256 --cpus="2" --memory="256m" -p 8081:80 performancetest2`

As you can see the difference is in the CPU allotted. I was expecting some improvement in the amount of time it takes to finish 10000 requests. But to my surprise it took almost exactly the same about of time i.e `40 seconds` in both cases.

How is this possible? The API is very simple. There isn't much going on there. There are no external calls or IO operations.

The memory utilization never even reached 100mb in both cases.

I am calling the API from host using the following code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/WeatherForecast");
    Task[] tasks = new Task[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));

        client.GetAsync("WeatherForecast");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you test it? Are you sure that the problem is not on the side generating the load?

Comment: `Task[] tasks = new Task[10000];` does not mean that you have actually have 10_000 concurrent requests. The load generated is limited by the settings of the task scheduler for example.

Comment: @GuruStron I know. Actually I could just replace it with int value 10000 in the forloop. But since I am not Awaiting the call, there should be 10000 parallel requests. I am calling the API asynchronously.

Comment: _"But since I am not Awaiting the call, there should be 10000 parallel requests"_ - no, it means that you will have 10_000 of tasks created but how many will be actually concurrently executed still is limited. For example check out the [`ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads?view=net-8.0) with the second parameter being `out int completionPortThreads` - _"The maximum number of asynchronous I/O threads in the thread pool."_.

Comment: And to not forget that `HttpClient` can limit number of requests to the same domain too. I would try to add some middleware which would count number of actually concurrently executed requests on the server.

Comment: Also it seems that your code is missing `tasks[i] = client.GetAsync("WeatherForecast");` and then `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. Also among the potential blockers you can have thread pool starvation too.

Comment: @GuruStron I think it probably is how I am calling the API running on docker after all. Because I noticed that the breakpoint reaches outside of for loop after almost as long as it takes for all requests to finish(I added await all) May be I should try using a software tool for that's generally used for testing.

Comment: Yes, in the nutshell you should use appropriate tools. For example [NBomber](https://nbomber.com/) is quite popular AFAIK (no affiliation). There are a lot of other load testing/load generating tools.

Comment: Also move the header manipulation outside of the loop (`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); ...`) And run the load testing tool in release mode without debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Try to batch these 10000 task - 100 tasks in one batch. And use at the end of each batch `await Task.WhenAll(batchTasks);`
It will look like:

```
int batchSize = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += batchSize)
{
    Task[] batchTasks = new Task[batchSize];
    for (int j = 0; j < batchSize; j++)
    {
        // ...
        batchTasks[j] = client.GetAsync("WeatherForecast");
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(batchTasks);
}
```